# What are mixed methods with essential Neumann boundary condition?

Tags: boundary-value-problem, weak-derivatives, finite-element-method

I have been implementing Neumann conditions as essential conditions in FEM schemes with successful results and was wondering whether this type of boundary condition was previously implemented.

I have seen a few papers that discuss the topic which claim their idea is original. However, I have seen in a FEM forum the following sentence:

> There are cases where the Dirichlet BC can become a natural BC (Nitsche’s method
> →
> related to discontinuous Galerkin method) and Neumann BC can be transformed into an essential condition using the so called **mixed methods**. But for our “Beginner’s course” we can assume that the Dirichlet BC is an essential BC and the Neumannn a natural one.

https://www.simscale.com/forum/t/the-finite-element-method-fundamentals-physical-problems-2/28665

However, What would be "mixed methods" in this case? Searches on mixed methods did not supply much besides the other papers which claim originality.

Comment: You might want to look into [A Simple Introduction to the Mixed Finite Element Method](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-03695-3) by Gatica or [Mixed Finite Element Methods and Applications](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-36519-5) by Boffi, Fortin, Brezzi as a reference for the "mixed methods." The essential-natural swap for Poisson problem and the like is caused by introduction of new variable $\nabla u$ for which the Neumann condition becomes essential (imposed on the function space) and Dirichlet condition becomes natural (goes to variatonal rhs).

Comment: @Korf Hey Thank you very much, you can put it as answer for internet points :)